# Do CloudKit overage charges apply automatically?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

The free requests per second limit for CloudKit is 40. If my app goes over 40 will my account be charged automatically or the specific requests above the first 40 will be rejected?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the source, but I remember reading once that Apple looks at the overall usage on a month-by-month basis. They won't automatically reject requests if you go over 40 per second in a single instance. Instead, they will watch the average and start billing you on request amounts that are consistently higher than the free tier allows.